# java stack overflow error?

Tags: java, unix, recursion, stack-overflow

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Search.mergeSort(Search.java:41)
at Search.mergeSort(Search.java:43)
at Search.mergeSort(Search.java:43)
at Search.mergeSort(Search.java:43)
at Search.mergeSort(Search.java:43)
```

I keep getting this error when I try to run my program. My program is supposed to take string input from a file and sort it using this algorithm. Any ideas? Problematic lines from code:

```
public static void mergeSort(String[] word, int p, int r){
int q;
if(p<r){
q=p+r/2;
mergeSort(word,p,q);
mergeSort(word, q+1,r);
merge(word, p, q, r);
}
}
```

***EDIT***

These two functions sort the String array by dividing the array in half, sorting each half separately, and merging them together. Int q is the halfway point, and the arrays being evaluated are from word[p] to word[q] and word[q+1] to word[r]. here's merge function:

```
public static void merge(String[] word, int p, int q, int r){
    int n1 = q-p+1;
    int n2 = r-q;
    String[] L = new String[n1];
    String[] R = new String[n2];
    int i, j, k;

    for(i=0; i<n1; i++) L[i] = word[p+i];
    for(j=0; j<n2; j++) R[j] = word[q+r+1];
    i=0; j=0;
    for(k=p; k<=r; k++){
        if(i<n1 && j<n2){
            if(L[i].compareTo(R[j])<0){
                word[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            }else{
                word[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
        }else if(i<n1){
            word[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }else if(j<n2){
            word[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the full code including merge because we don't know what's going on in merge.  It'd be helpful to know what's on line 43 as well.

Comment: It's pretty unusual for a function to call itself twice in two lines.

Comment: "Infinite" recursion.  Unless the `if` statement caps the recursion, this will happen.  A little hard to get one's head around what the p/q/r computations are doing and how that might (or might not) end the recursion.

Comment: @chubbsondubs - I don't see how what goes on in merge could affect how deep recursion occurs.  It's purely a function of the p/q/r stuff.

Comment: Insert a println statement to print out the p, q, and r values for each recursion.  (Note that this will be A LOT of data, since growth is exponential.)  (It would help understanding to add a couple of extra parms to indicate recursion depth and whether left or right call, and print those too.)

Comment: (I guess I'd like to know what line 43 is as well.)

Comment: I wanted it so I could just run your code and see it in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Walk through with a debugger. You'll see exactly how it's leading to an infinite recursion. IDEs (Eclipse, IntelliJ) have them built in.

Comment: Unfortunately, recursive problems can quickly get out of control and beyond one's ability to follow if you attempt to use only a debugger.  You generally need some sort of "printed" trace as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your calculation of `q` is incorrect.  It is supposed to be the halfway point between `p` and `r`, and the way to calculate that is:

```
 q = p + (r - p) / 2;
```

or

```
 q = (p + r) / 2;
```

But you've written:

```
 q = p + r / 2;
```

which is equivalent to

```
 q = p + (r / 2);
```

Comment: I did this and it seemed to fix the stack overflow error but a new error was generated:

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
 at Search.merge(Search.java:58)
 at Search.mergeSort(Search.java:46)
 at Search.mergeSort(Search.java:44)
 at Search.mergeSort(Search.java:44)
 at Search.mergeSort(Search.java:45)
 at Search.main(Search.java:31)

Comment: I think you need to follow djechlin's advice.

Answer (score 0):

When making recursive methods, you need some base case, otherwise you'll get infinite recursion like you are right now.

In your `mergeSort` method, **you don't have a base case**. You need to put a check in to see if the part you're sorting is already sorted; if `word[p..r]` is sorted, then you should not call `mergeSort`